# Best Practices ViewModel Validation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I am using `DataAnnotations` to validate my `ViewModel` on client side with `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` and on server side in **ASP.NET MVC** application.

Not so long time ago, I figured out that I can write validation like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

That way I can easily define some general strings in **config** or in resources and always use it in `DataAnnotations`. So it will be easier to change validation messages in my whole application in future.

Also I know that there is a **FluentValidation** library that allows to add validation rules to already existing `ViewModel`. I know that there is a problem with Add/Edit `ViewModels` that could have similar fields but different ValidationRules.

Another problem that comes from client validation is that html newly added to **DOM** (using **ajax request**) should be parsed to enable validation. This is how I do it:

```
$('#some-ajax-form').data('validator', null); 
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#some-ajax-form');
```

So I have some questions:

1. Is there some other useful practises that could help centralize all validation rules in application?
2. What's is a best way to solve Add/Edit `ViewModel` Validation problem? Can I use `DataAnnotations` with **FluentValidation** or separate Add and Edit `ViewModels` still is a best option?
3. Is there any better way to initialize validation on new **DOM** elements that received with **ajax call** other that I mention?

---

I'm not asking how to create my own `DataValidators` I know how to do it. I seeking of ways how to use them in more productive and easy maintainable way.

Comment: Note you need to reset the validator before parsing - `$('#some-ajax-form').data('validator', null); $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#some-ajax-form');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for important detail, i added this to question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer your 3th question first: No there is no easier way then what you are doing. Two lines of code to get it working can hardly be easier. Although there is a plug-in you could use, like explained in the question [unobtrusive validation not working with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14982495/434949)

Your first question, how to centralize validation, I normally use a separate class file to store all my validation rules. This way I don't have to browse through every single class file to find the rules, but have them all in one place. If that's better, is  matter of choice. The main reason I started to use it, is to be able to add validation to auto-generated classes, like classes from the Entity Framework.

So I have a file called `ModelValidation.cs` in my data layer, and have code for all my models like

```
/// <summary>
/// Validation rules for the <see cref="Test"/> object
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// 2015-01-26: Created
/// </remarks>
[MetadataType(typeof(TestValidation))]
public partial class Test { }
public class TestValidation
{
    /// <summary>Name is required</summary>
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Text is multiline</summary>
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Now as you noticed I don't provide the actual error message. I use [conventions by Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx/) to add the messages. It makes it simple to add localized validation rules.

It basically comes down to a recource file containing something like:

```
Test_Name = "Provide name"
Test_Name_Required = "Name is required"
```

And these messages and naming will be used when you call regular `MVC view` code like

```
<div class="editor-container">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) <!--"Provide name"-->
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) <!--"Name is required"-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Your second question, about different validation for add/edit can be handled in two ways. The best way, would be to use views as they are actually intended. That means you don't pass your actual models to the views, but you create a view model that contains only the data. So you have a view model for `Create` with the proper validation rules and a view model for `Edit` with the proper rules, and when they pass you insert the result in your actual model.
This however requires a lot more code and manual work, so I can imagine you're not really willing to do it like this.

Another option would be to use [conditional validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285348/434949) like explained by viperguynaz. Now instead of a boolean, my classes that require a change between edit/add have a `primary key` `Id` `int`. So I check if `Id>0` to determine if it is an edit or not.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to update validation on every ajax call, you could use `jQuery ajaxComplete`. This will revalidate all forms after every ajax request.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.data('validator', null); 
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($el);
    })
});
```

If this is something you want, depends on how often you receive a form via `AJAX`. If you have a lot of `AJAX` request, like polling a status every 10seconds, than you don't want this. If you have an occasional `AJAX` request, that mostly contains a form, then you could use it.

If your `AJAX` returns a form you want to validate, then yes, it is good practise to update the validation. But I guess a better question would be "Do I really need to send the form by AJAX?"
`AJAX` is fun and useful, but it should be used with care and thought.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you say, is it good practice to handle validation on every **ajax** call that returns `html` with `form` in it. And can i do it once in one general `js` script if we talking about **ASP.NET MVC** project?

Comment: I'am trying to implement what you advice in answer. Am i understand correcly that if i use [conditional validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation/5285348#5285348) and implement `IValidatableObject` interface i loose client unobtrusive validation?

Comment: See the full example as viperguynaz commented: http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/MVC3-Custom-Validation-Attributes-for-Client-Server-Side-Validation-with-Unobtrusive-Ajax

Answer (score 8):

Like others have said, there is no such tricks, no easy way to centralize your validations.

I have a couple of approaches that might interest you. Take note that this is how "we" solved the same problem before. Its up to you if you can find our solution maintainable and productive.

> I know that there is a problem with Add/Edit ViewModels that could have similar fields but different ValidationRules.

**Inheritance Approach**

You can achieve centralized validation using a base class, and use subclasses for specific validations.

```
// Base class. That will be shared by the add and edit
public class UserModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; } // Notice the virtual?

    // This validation is shared on both Add and Edit.
    // A centralized approach.
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

// Used for creating a new user.
public class AddUserViewModel : UserModel
{
    // AddUser has its own specific validation for the first name.
    [Required]
    public override string FirstName { get; set; } // Notice the override?
}

// Used for updating a user.
public class EditUserViewModel : UserModel
{
    public override string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**Extending the ValidationAttribute Approach**

Using custom `ValidationAtribute`, you can achieve centralized validation. This is only the basic implementation, I am just showing you the idea.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class CustomEmailAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public CustomEmailAttribute()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "Error Message Here";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string email = value as string;
        
        // Put validation logic here.

        return valid;
    }
}
```

You would use as such

```
public class AddUserViewModel
{
    [CustomEmail]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [CustomEmail]
    public string RetypeEmail { get; set; }
}
```

> Is there any better way to initialize validation on new DOM elements that received with ajax call other that I mention?

This is how I rebind validators on dynamic elements (jQuery)

```
/** 
* Rebinds the MVC unobtrusive validation to the newly written
* form inputs. This is especially useful for forms loaded from
* partial views or ajax.
*
* Credits: http://www.mfranc.com/javascript/unobtrusive-validation-in-partial-views/
* 
* Usage: Call after pasting the partial view
*
*/
function refreshValidators(formSelector) {
    //get the relevant form 
    var form = $(formSelector);
    // delete validator in case someone called form.validate()
    $(form).removeData("validator");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
};
```

Usage (JQuery)

```
// Dynamically load the add-user interface from a partial view.
$('#add-user-div').html(partialView);

// Call refresh validators on the form
refreshValidators('#add-user-div form');
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have seen inheritance approach, but really don't know is it way better than separate `ViewModels`? I mean, can i override property attributes if it's already been overrided? If I inherit from `EditUserViewModel` in your example?  About validating dynamic attributes it's pretty much the same that @Hugo offer i gess.

Answer (score 5):

Jquery unobtrusive validation works by applying attributes to INPUT elements that instruct the client library to validate that element using a rule that is mapped to the respective attribute. For instance: the `data-val-required` html attribute is recognized by the unobtrusive library, and causes it to validate that element against the corresponding rule.

In **.NET MVC**, you can make this happen automatically for some specific rules by applying attributes to your model properties. Attributes like `Required` and `MaxLength` work because the Html helpers know how to read those attributes and add corresponding HTML attributes to their output that the unobtrusive library understands.

If you add validation rules to your models in `IValidatableObject` or using **FluentValidation**, the HTML Helper will not see these rules, and therefore not try to translate them to unobtrusive attributes.

In other words the "free" coordination you've seen thus far by applying attributes to your model and getting client validation is limited to validation attributes, and further, is limited (by default) only to those attributes that map directly to unobtrusive rules.

The bright side is, you are free to create your own custom validation attributes, and by implementing `IClientValidatable`, the Html Helper will add an unobtrusive attribute with the name of your choosing that you can then teach the unobtrusive library to respect.

This is a custom attribute we use that ensures that one date falls after another date:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class DateGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    string otherPropertyName;

    public DateGreaterThanAttribute(string otherPropertyName, string errorMessage = null)
        : base(errorMessage)
    {
        this.otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ValidationResult validationResult = ValidationResult.Success;
        // Using reflection we can get a reference to the other date property, in this example the project start date
        var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
        // Let's check that otherProperty is of type DateTime as we expect it to be
        if (otherPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Equals(new DateTime().GetType()))
        {
            DateTime toValidate = (DateTime)value;
            DateTime referenceProperty = (DateTime)otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            // if the end date is lower than the start date, than the validationResult will be set to false and return
            // a properly formatted error message
            if (toValidate.CompareTo(referenceProperty) < 1)
            {
                validationResult = new ValidationResult(this.GetErrorMessage(validationContext));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // do nothing. We're not checking for a valid date here
        }

        return validationResult;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return "must be greater than " + otherPropertyName;
    }

    private string GetErrorMessage(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!this.ErrorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return this.ErrorMessage;
        else
        {
            var thisPropName = !validationContext.DisplayName.IsNullOrEmpty() ? validationContext.DisplayName : validationContext.MemberName;
            var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
            var otherPropName = otherPropertyInfo.Name;
            // Check to see if there is a Displayname attribute and use that to build the message instead of the property name
            var displayNameAttrs = otherPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false);
            if (displayNameAttrs.Length > 0)
                otherPropName = ((DisplayNameAttribute)displayNameAttrs[0]).DisplayName;

            return "{0} must be on or after {1}".FormatWith(thisPropName, otherPropName);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        //string errorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName);
        string errorMessage = ErrorMessageString;

        // The value we set here are needed by the jQuery adapter
        ModelClientValidationRule dateGreaterThanRule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        dateGreaterThanRule.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        dateGreaterThanRule.ValidationType = "dategreaterthan"; // This is the name the jQuery adapter will use
        //"otherpropertyname" is the name of the jQuery parameter for the adapter, must be LOWERCASE!
        dateGreaterThanRule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherpropertyname", otherPropertyName);

        yield return dateGreaterThanRule;
    }
}
```

We may apply the attribute to the model as such:

```
    [DateGreaterThan("Birthdate", "You have to be born before you can die")]
    public DateTime DeathDate { get; set; }
```

This causes the Html helper to render the following two attributes on the `INPUT` element when calling `Html.EditorFor` on a model property that has this attribute:

```
data-val-dategreaterthan="You have to be born before you can die" 
data-val-dategreaterthan-otherpropertyname="Birthdate"
```

So far so good, but now I have to teach unobtrusive validation what to do with those attributes. First, I have to create a named rule for jquery validation:

```
    // Value is the element to be validated, params is the array of name/value pairs of the parameters extracted from the HTML, element is the HTML element that the validator is attached to
jQuery.validator.addMethod("dategreaterthan", function (value, element, params) {
    return Date.parse(value) > Date.parse($(params).val());
});
```

And then add an unobtrusive adaptor for that rule that maps the attribute to the rule:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("dategreaterthan", ["otherpropertyname"], function (options) {
    options.rules["dategreaterthan"] = "#" + options.params.otherpropertyname;
    options.messages["dategreaterthan"] = options.message;
});
```

After Ive done all this, I can get this validation rule for "free" anywhere else in my application just by applying that attribute to the model.

To address your question of how to apply rules conditionally based on whether the model is being used in an add or an edit operation: this can probably be done by adding additional logic to your custom attributes and having both the `IsValid` method the `GetClientValidation` rules method attempt to glean some context from the model using reflection. But honestly, that seems like a mess to me. For this, I'd just rely on server validation and whatever rules you choose to apply using `IValidatableObject.Validate()` method.

Comment: Thank you for detail reply, but you answered on different question. I **don't** asking how to **EXTEND** `DataValidators`. I understand that i need just create custom validation attribute and add client side validation to unobtrusive adapter as you mension in your answer. I asking about some good practicies or tricks with validation attribute like parametrised strings in my example. Also you did not say anything about ajax form validation. I update the question.

Comment: Yes, I seem to have been unclear on your question the way it was phrased. I attempted to answer "good practices for centralizing validation logic" (read by me: sharing logic) by explaining how a custom attribute can handle both client and server validation. That also explained why FluentValidation isnt going to address your concern.

Attribute parameters can only be constants, so switching strings based on config file values won't work, but a resource file will. 

I didn't address #3 because unobtrusive.parse is designed to do exactly what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to have Client Validation, like one that Microsoft uses for MVC, works with `ubobtrusive` library created by itself for integrating with `DataAnnotations`. **But**, after some years of working with this helpful tool, I tired of it which is boring and tedious to employ in cases that we need separate `ViewModels` (and likely separate `ViewModels` for create/edit templates).

Another way is using MVVM which works well with MVC since the two paradigms are quite similar. *In MVC you have a Model that is bounded just on the server side when the client send content to the server*. *While MVVM binds a local model with the UI directly on the client*. Take a look at the [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/), the known one which help you to understand how to work with MVVM.

With this in mind, I'll answer your questions in order:

1. You can't centralize validation rules in the application unless by
   creating shared classes and reuse them by calling in separate
   Models/ViewModels.
2. If you wanna use Microsoft Validator, separating the Add/Edit
   ViewModels is a best option because of its readability and easier way to
   change.
3. I never said that the *Knockoutjs* is better, they are different
   from each other, just gives you some flexibility to create views
   based on model requirements. This also take you away from
   centralizing validations :(

Comment: Thank you for reply. I know that there is _Knockoutjs_ and even more complex _AngularJS_ that can give me 2 way binding and in general case make MVC on client side with just service (can be RESTfull) on server side. But am I right that you still should validate your model on server and client side? And without `DataBingings` it will end up with more code that separated on client and server side?

Comment: @teovankot Yes, you're right. Albeit `DataAnnotations` with help of `unobtrusive` library perform validation in both sides.