# How to validate multiple, separate models in a single ViewModel using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have two separate models: `ModelA` and `ModelB`. I also have a ViewModel: `TheViewModel`. `TheViewModel` contains an instance of `ModelA` as well as `ModelB`.

`ModelA` and `ModelB` have their own respective properties and [`Required`]s. However, when I go to post the form, `TheViewModel` only validates `ModelA` and ignores `ModelB`

How can I validate multiple models using one ViewModel?

Some code snippets:

**ModelA**

```
public class ModelA
{
    [Required]
    public string TheID { get; set; }
    public string TheName { get; set; }
}
```

**ModelB**

```
public class ModelB
{
    [Required]
    public string TheCode { get; set; }
    public string TheType { get; set; }
}
```

**TheViewModel**

```
public class TheViewModel
{
    public ModelA ModelAExample { get; set; }
    public ModelB ModelBExample { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(TheViewModel vm)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }

   return View(vm.ModelAExample, vm.ModelBExample));
}
```

The ModelState will only validate if the `TheID` property in `ModelA` is valid, and not `TheCode` in `ModelB`

Comment: You should also include `[Required]` on both properties in class `TheViewModel`. Also what is the value of `TheCode` when you say that the `ModelState.IsValid` returns true when it should not? Finally ou should pass variable `vm` to the `View` method as a View takes 1 model not multiple models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only  need to pass vm only  to view . model binding happening with one model only.if you  want to pass multiple model in this case youhave  to use  Dynamic objects like ViewBag etc.....

```
 return View(vm);
```

Then you can bind View Model With you View.The code which you given will not run  return View(vm.ModelAExample, vm.ModelBExample`));` here it will throw syntax error

[Best Practices ViewModel Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090143/best-practices-viewmodel-validation-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

This won't compile:

```
return View(vm.ModelAExample, vm.ModelBExample));
```

If you use vm as ViewModel, the validation will be correct:

```
return View(vm)
```